# Is there a minimum question score to get onto the Multicollider?

Tags: support, hot-questions

I'm referring this question: [Is C/C++ one language or two languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14330370/is-c-c-one-language-or-two-languages)

At the time of this writing:

- The question is less than 1 hour old.
- The question is at -1.
- The combined score of the answers is ***49 votes***.

By now, I would have expected this question to have skyrocketed to near the top of the Multicollider.

According to the [formula posted by Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions) (which I believe is out of date now), the combined answer score *should* be enough to offset the low question score. But the question is not on the Multicollider.

Is there a strict minimum question score to get onto the Multicollider? - regardless of how heavily upvoted the answers are?

Comment: I'll also add that the question is currently open. It has two close votes right now, and will likely be closed - which would exclude it from the Multicollider. But as of this writing, it is still open.

Comment: Far as that question goes and for my money... [zneak's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14330370/is-c-c-one-language-or-two-languages#comment19916075_14330370) just about sums it up. The question is clear and answerable (and *answered* fairly well at that) even if possibly naive to every experienced programmer out there. I cleaned up the comments a bit, and I hope it stays open without further drama.

Comment: @AnnaLear 3 days ago I asked [a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163222/cant-understand-close-reason-too-localized) on meta, about one other SO question which was closed as **too localized**.. Too localized says question is only likely to  help a very few programmers in internet and not applicable to general public...  Well I really would like to know how many programmers the question referenced here helps? To me the question is too localized then.. I voted it to close.

Comment: @Krishnabhadra I reopened that question since I agree - it's not all that localized. However, I strongly suggest you do not cast close votes essentially out of spite. If a question was wrongly closed, it's not a reason to go ahead and start wrongly closing other questions in the same way just to prove a point.

Comment: @AnnaLear **However, I strongly suggest you do not cast close votes essentially out of spite** Oops.. There was nothing like that. I am not someone who normally use **too localized** as close reason.. I just ignore those question, and let others do the job. But from meta question I posted, what I understood is **too localized** can be used when the question do not help future visitors much, question too basic for most people to search. I still think this question tick the mark. So I stand with my close vote, but happy that community made the decision.

Comment: BTW I agree with you that this question cannot be considered as **non constructive** since no way it results in long debate, solicit discussions etc..